# Intercept barcode scanning event

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, prism, barcode-scanner

I'm developing an application that will be installed in mobile devices with integrated barcode scanner.
In my page there are different types of widget, included a not visible Entry that I want to use temporary to store the scanned barcode value.
The problem is that the user can tap and interact with all the widgets in the page and, in an unknown moment, he can scan a barcode.
I want to force the focus in this invisible Entry or intercept the text typed (because a barcode scan is like a keyboard typing). How I can do that?
I'm developing with Xamarin.Forms with Prism framework for MVVM.

N.B. = The barcode scanning is not with the cam.

Comment: The below answer suggesting the use of the Xamarin SDK is the best but an alternative approach would be to use intents.  The wedge functionality you describe (sending barcode data as keystrokes) is one output mechanism, some manufacturers including the Zebra TC51 as mentioned in the answer also allow an Intent to be sent with the barcode data - you can then intercept the intent in your Xamarin app and populate the UI field accordingly.

Comment: Hi Darryn, can you explain me how to intercept the scanning event and data? Have you got an example?

Comment: For full disclosure, I work for Zebra but with that in mind I have a sample app in my personal github to demonstrate how to intercept intents: https://github.com/darryncampbell/DataWedge-API-Exerciser Follow the device configuration section in the repo readme then the sample app will receive it, e.g. this line is displaying a scan sent via Broadcast intent: https://github.com/darryncampbell/DataWedge-API-Exerciser/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/zebra/datawedgeexerciser/MainActivity.java#L488

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not a good Idea to use "Keyboard emulation" to read barcode from scanner. I don't know what are you using (an external barcode reader connected via bluetooth, an integrated barcode reader) but usully you should not have an Entry with a Focus to read a string received from a scanner.

If you are using an external barcode reader connected via bluetooth, I suggest to read [this article](https://acaliaro.wordpress.com/2017/02/07/connect-a-barcode-reader-to-a-xamarin-forms-app-via-bluetooth/)

Otherwise, if you are using an integrated scanner (like TC51 Zebra device) you should use the SDK.

If you are using TC51, you can find here the [SDK for Xamarin](http://techdocs.zebra.com/emdk-for-xamarin/2-2/guide/about/) and [here](http://techdocs.zebra.com/emdk-for-xamarin/2-2/tutorial/barcodeapitutorial/) a sample how to use it in Xamarin.Android.

If you have to test in in Xamarin Forms, you have to do the same thing you are doing with Xamarin.Android and when you receive a barcode, send to your XF app with a MessagingCenter

```
void scanner_Data(object sender, Scanner.DataEventArgs e)
{
    ScanDataCollection scanDataCollection = e.P0;

if ((scanDataCollection != null) && (scanDataCollection.Result == ScannerResults.Success))
{
    IList<ScanDataCollection.ScanData> scanData = scanDataCollection.GetScanData();

    foreach (ScanDataCollection.ScanData data in scanData)
    {
        displaydata(data.LabelType + " : " + data.Data);

        // Something like this
        Xamarin.Forms.MessagingCenter.Send<App> ((App)Xamarin.Forms.Application.Current, "Barcode", data.Data);
    }
}


}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. Now I try to do the same in Xamarin.Forms.

Comment: Alessandro I tried to include the Zebra SDK in my project but I have 2 problems: The first is that now the application doesn't works in a traditional smarthphone (Samsung Galaxy S4), maybe because it doesn't has scanner hardware. The application crashed on startup. I tried with android:required="false" in AndroidManifest.xml but without good results. The second problem is that I don't know how messageCenter works. I tried to send the message from the MainActivity of the Android Project (where I can have a reference to Zebra SDK) to the Portable project without success.

Comment: Another note: I can't debug because I don't have the usb cable for Zebra.

Comment: Why about external barcode scanners connected by wire to device?  Why does it has to be either camera scanning or blue tooth scanning?

Comment: @TeoVr81 Teo, I am trying to figure same with External barcode scanners such as Honeywell's (cable connected or bluetooth connected).  Have you had any success in this area for Xamarin.Forms (with .NET Standard 2.0) for iOS, Android, and UWP?

Comment: @AlessandroCaliaro What do you mean by "keyboard emulation"?

Comment: https://www.b4x.com/android/forum/threads/bluetooth-barcode-scanner-in-hid-mode.85370/

Comment: @cd491415 I haven't tried with external barcode scanners

Comment: I still dont understand why keyboard emulation is bad if scanners are input devices just like keyboards are

Comment: With keyboard emulation you should be sure to have ui control with a focus and it can receive chars, otherwise you loose data. For this reason is better to have a scanner in SPP mode so you can open a Bluetooth socket and you have full control about receiver data.

Comment: @AlessandroCaliaro Thanks.  I agree 100% with that.  But imagine situation you are at the counter and all clerk does is scan items one by one and they are always scanned into same field.  Then no, for that, no need to worry about SDKs at all.  But I agree, if you were in a warehouse or so and you scan into multiple fields, then yes, you need SDKs because (a) you would have to manage field focus and (b) each field focus would pop up keyboard which is annoying.  That is why I say, this works for simple scanning only.